# Listview using arraylist

Tags: android

How can we create the listview using arraylist in a simple way

Comment: please elaborate and search a little over the internet before asking questions.... you can find plenty of work related to your question. Check this link: http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-listview.html and this: http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidListView/article.html

Answer (score 0):

```
ListView lv=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.lv01);  String[] names = new String[] { "Show Hidden Files", "Suffle Tab Position"};

    // Create an ArrayAdapter, that will actually make the Strings above
    // appear in the ListView
    this.setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_checked, names));
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a `BaseAdapter`, and override the necessary methods to make it use the `ArrayList<?>`.

[In this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5645104/android-expandablelistview/5645596#5645596) the `MyELAdapter` is used for an expandable list view, but the base logic is there, it populates the listview with `Parent` instances from an `ArrayList<Parent>`.