# Listview and animation

Tags: android, android-listview, android-animation

I'm using listview animation from API DEMOS, example 2. here's the snippet from OnCreate method:

```
ListView listview = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);

AnimationSet set = new AnimationSet(true);
Animation animation = new AlphaAnimation(0.0f, 1.0f);
animation.setDuration(50);
set.addAnimation(animation);

animation = new TranslateAnimation(
    Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f,
    Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, -1.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f);

animation.setDuration(200);
set.addAnimation(animation);

LayoutAnimationController controller = new LayoutAnimationController(set, 0.5f);
listview.setLayoutAnimation(controller);
```

At some point in the future, `notifyDataSetInvalidated()` is called upon list's adapter, and my list is refreshed. but the items are not shown in animation any more.

Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to reanimate your LayoutController after your data set changes, call the method [startLayoutAnimation()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#startLayoutAnimation%28%29) of the view.

Comment: this is for a viewgroup. If I want, for example, to replay the animation on a recycled view  y cant call View.startLayoutAnimation() . It doesn't exist

Answer (score 0):

You should check out this thread about [difference between notifyDataSetChanged() and notifyDataSetInvalidated()](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/1tsRQczqbt0) (Link updated to point to Romain Guy's answer!)

In short the difference is:

- `notifyDataSetChanged`: The items in the data set are changed (added / removed / updated / reordered, whatever).
- `notifyDataSetInvalidated`: The data source of the adapter is no longer available.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5645104/android-expandablelistview/5645596#5645596) you can find a working sample with `notifyDataSetInvalidated` function in use. Probably it will do the trick with your animation problem as well.