# Change background color of each row in ExpandableListView?

Tags: java, android

Hey, Is it possible to change the background of a specified row in an ExpandableListView? What I want is: 1st row blue, 2nd red, 3rd blue, 4th red.....  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to check out [this thread: Android ExpandableListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5645104/android-expandablelistview).
There is a [working sample](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5645104/android-expandablelistview/5645596#5645596) with the functionality you want (colorize the rows based on the data they hold).

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is possible, and you have to use custom adapter for your Expandable list view.

```
 @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild,
            View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
       //......
        //...... Your code for row view
       //.....

        //Now write here code for set colors for rows
        if(childPosition % 2 == 0) {
           convertView.setBackgroundColor("#0000FF"); // use this when you want to use hexa value of colors
        } else {
           convertView.setBackgroundColor("#FF0000"); // use this when you want to use hexa value of colors
        }

        //setBackgroundResource(android.R.color.transparent); // use this for predefined colors at place of setBackground


       return convertView;
    }
```

Read [this](http://techdroid.kbeanie.com/2010/09/expandablelistview-on-android.html) article, here example and source code also available.

Comment: I get this error: "The method getChildView(int, int, boolean, View, ViewGroup) of type Main2 must override or implement a supertype method"  .. could this be because I'm extending my class to Activity rather than BaseExpandableListAdapter ?

Answer (score 0):

Of course.  You will simply need to manually set the background on the views as you create or recreate them.  Do this in the adapter in the method

```
getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
```

Based on the group and child position