# How can I create a 2 level or 3 level expandable ListView?

Tags: android

I am planning to create an expandable `Listview` that has more than 2 levels. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve an n-level `ExpandableListView`, if you use it with your custom `BaseExpandableListAdapter`.

In this extended adapter, you override the

```
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, 
    View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
```

method, assign an ExpandableListView instance to the convertView, and return it.

If you have overriden all the necessary methods in your adapter, this should work.

[In this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5645104/android-expandablelistview/5645596#5645596) you can find a working sample of `ExpandableListView` using `BaseExpandableListAdapter`. If you modify its `getGroupView` method to return an other `ExpandableListView` instance, you'll have a multilevel listview.

Comment: Surely that should be ExpandableListView, not BaseExpandableListAdapter in the convertView?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! :) stupid mistake, i've corrected it

Comment: You missed one (directly below the override) - I've tried to edit for you, it's stuck in peer review ATM

Comment: Thanks rekaszeru, I will try out that.

Comment: Can you give me a little sample here. I am so stucked.