# Android - CheckedTextView/CheckBoxes in ExpandableListView

Tags: android, checkbox, expandablelistview, checkedtextview

I've tried looking over the internet but I generally don't understand how to implement this at all.

What I have is a quiz app with many categories, and some categories are subcategories. Here is a typical example list:

Animals

- Dogs
- Cats
- Elephants

Countries

Fruits

Vegetables

- Carrots
- Potatoes

I want to be able to expand and collapse Animals and Vegetables so that individual categories within can be selected. Categories without subitems can also be selected.

I thought it best to use an expandablelistview with checkedtextviews or checkboxes. Does anyone have a link to a tutorial that can show me how to do this or if it isn't too much bother show me how to do it?

Thank you very much

Comment: Just check this out <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5645104/android-expandablelistview?rq=1>

Comment: possible duplicate of [ANDROID - ExpandableListView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5645104/android-expandablelistview)