# How to add radiogroups to a listview dynamically? (Or an expandable listview)

Tags: android, dynamic, android-listview, radio-button, expandablelistview

I want to create a feedback form such that there are radio button options in an expandable list view instead of a sub list, the number of radio buttons and elements in the list is dynamic. I have found a lot of tutorials and working examples of a simple listview with radio buttons but nothing that serves my purpose.

Any help on integrating expandable listview and radio buttons dynamically will be highly appreciated!

Regards,
Garima.

Comment: check this link it will help you to add radiobuttons in e[xpandable listview][1] 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5645104/android-expandablelistview

Comment: Many thanks but I had already checked this one out!